# Saving audio files and navigating between views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio

I'm having trouble saving recorded audio files and playing them back after navigating between views.

I've been using the tutorial at http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28iOS_4%29

I've added in a line to save the audio file, so my `prepareForAudioRecording` looks like the code below. This method is called in `viewDidLoad`.

```
-(void) prepareForAudioRecording
{
    btnPlay.enabled = NO;
    btnStop.enabled = NO;

    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"page1.caf"];

    //this line added to save the audio file
    [audioPlayer.data writeToFile:soundFilePath atomically:YES];


    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary 
                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
                                    AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
                                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                                    AVSampleRateKey,
                                    nil];

    NSError *error = nil;

    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                     initWithURL:soundFileURL
                     settings:recordSettings
                     error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    } else {
        [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
    }
}
```

As I said, i can record the audio and then play back the audio while in the same view controller, but when i navigate away from the view and return to it I can't playback the recording.

Firstly the play and stop buttons were disabled, which i thought should have only happen when the view was first loaded - but even when i enabled them and pressed the play button, there was no audio.

My other methods are below for my play, stop and record button.

```
- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    if (!audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        btnStop.enabled = YES;
        btnRecord.enabled = NO;

        //if (audioPlayer)
            //[audioPlayer release];
        NSError *error;

        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                       initWithContentsOfURL:audioRecorder.url                                    
                       error:&error];

        audioPlayer.delegate = self;

        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", 
                  [error localizedDescription]);
        else
            [audioPlayer play];
    }
}

-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    btnRecord.enabled = YES;
    btnStop.enabled = NO;
}
-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Decode Error occurred");
}
-(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
}
-(void)audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Encode Error occurred");
}


- (IBAction)recordAudio:(id)sender {
    if (!audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        btnPlay.enabled = NO;
        btnStop.enabled = YES;
        [audioRecorder record];
    }
}

- (IBAction)stopAudio:(id)sender {
    btnStop.enabled = NO;
    btnPlay.enabled = YES;
    btnRecord.enabled = YES;

    if (audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        [audioRecorder stop];
    } else if (audioPlayer.playing) {
        [audioPlayer stop];
    }
}
```

I know there's a lot of code to look at there but if i'm missing out anything please let me know. I'd really appreciate any help with this, thanks.

**EDIT 1**: Ok, i've done a bit more investigating and opened up the folder where my audio files are saved. The audio records fine and the file size is around 400KB. When i push to the next view controller the filesize remains at 400KB. But as soon as i press my back button (not the preprogrammed one in the nav bar) the filesize goes to 4KB; an empty file. The code for my back button is simply:

```
- (IBAction)backPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Please help!

**EDIT 2**: It also happens with the back button in the nav bar too.

Answer (score 0):

You're allocating `audioPlayer` with `audioRecorder.url`. If *something happend* to `audioRecorder` it's `url` might be invalid.

Try setting `audioPlayer` this way:

```
- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    if (!audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        btnStop.enabled = YES;
        btnRecord.enabled = NO;

        NSArray *dirPaths;
        NSString *docsDir;

        dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"page1.caf"];

        NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

        NSError *error;

        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] nitWithContentsOfURL:soundFileUR                                    
                                                            error:&error];

        audioPlayer.delegate = self;

        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        else
            [audioPlayer play];
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean to replace `audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]                   initWithContentsOfURL:audioRecorder.url                             error:&error];` in my `playAudio` method or to add the above code into my `prepareForAudioRecording` method?

Comment: It appears to be demonstrating the same behavior with that new code above. It records and plays back the audio in the view controller, but the play button is disabled when i return to the view controller from another controller. I'm kind of confused as to why i'd declare the filepath again when i've already set it in my `prepareForAudioRecording` method?

Comment: As for redeclaring filepath - just for code-safety. If the play button gets disabled while you're navigating off the view controller then check if viewDidLoad gets called again (thus disabling play button).

Comment: Having just checked there, `viewDidLoad` is only called the first time. It is not called again when navigating between view controllers. Thanks for your help so far rokjarc.